# Touchpad Problem - shortly after login, it stops working

Tags: 11.10, touchpad

I've Ubuntu 11.10 and my problem is about the touchpad. At the beginning of my computer it's works fine, but after opening an application or a few minutes, it stops working and I have to use a USB mouse. Someone could help me? Thank you very much:)

Comment: I am experiencing the exact same behaviour... but uncheck of 'disable touchpad when typing' option didn't help at all. I have ps/2 touch pad before log in (can mouse to password field on gdm). When I log in, mouse immediately stops working. rmmod / modprobe doesnt' seem to help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem as well, the only thing that I did was in the terminal:

```
    unity --replace
```

after that it hasn't been an issue.

Comment: Perfect... also replacing the synaptic drivers! :D ;) Thanks

Comment: @ManuelAndrésVélez I also have the same problem. Can you tell me how you replaced the synaptic driver?

Comment: This is total overkill -- replace the entire desktop just for one driver?

Comment: I'm on 12.04, and this doesn't do anything for me.

Answer (score 12):

There is another command that works, and is perhaps more direct:

```
sudo modprobe -r psmouse && sudo modprobe psmouse
```

The problem is that it is not a permanent solution. I already tried adding **psmouse** to the */etc/modules* file, but the problem is not about the driver not loading, but crashing or something.

Does the unity replacement command work as a "permanent solution"?

Comment: are you talking about unity --replace for me it did.

Comment: This worked for me!

Answer (score 7):

If this happents, use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> to open a terminal and type:

```
synclient TouchpadOff=0
```

Comment: This is the best answer.  I used to use the modprobe method, but in 12.04, it causes unity or even X to crash.  This one does not even need to be root!

Answer (score 3):

These solutions didn't work for me (running ubuntu 12.10). The thing that did the trick is:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.peripherals.touchpad touchpad-enabled true
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

I was sucessful with the wollowing treatment:
   I plugged in a USB mouse
   Navigate to the touchpad and mouse settings (top right button -> system settings -> Mouse and Touchpad)
   I then unchecked the disable mouse when typing option.
   Reboot.

Worked fine using this since!  Perhaps there is some weird mouse locking issue related to this setting?

Comment: Although this wasn't exactly the fix for my mouse freeze, this helped in solving the issue on my Xubuntu, which was *Enable this device* option on the *Mouse Settings* dialog was getting unchecked everytime I login. Clicking on *Restore Defaults* fixed the issue. Never thought using the UI would be simpler, wasted time mucking around with conf files. Thanks!